# How do I make my user input as a variable in Java while dealing with J Option Pane

Tags: java, null, user-input, joptionpane

I'm a rookie java coder, and I was trying to make a program that receives value from the user in which I can assign whatever he/she enters as a variable so that it can be displayed in a box through `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("");`

If the user did not enter anything into the box (Meaning the user input value is equaled to null), java must respond with "You did not enter anything" in the form of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`.
Although it keeps saying one of my variables cant be "resolved"

here's where the error is:

```
String moviename; 

String  moviename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Whats you favourite movie?");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, moviename+", sounds like a good watch."); 
     
if (moviename.equals("null")) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter anything"); 
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have declared `moviename` twice

Comment: `moviename.equals("null")` should be `null == moviename`

Comment: You may want to also consider placing the entry response into an `else` block, for example: `if (moviename == null || moviename.trim().isEmpty()) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter anything"); } else {             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, moviename + ", sounds like a good watch.");         }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't seem to notice that while skimming my code. Much appreciated

Comment: @DevilsHnd, Thanks for helping a rookie coder out :), I was wondering why it still kept on showing error messages in the console, regards.